# Different ways of record selection in an extjs grid

Tags: extjs

In an extjs grid to get selected records, we use:

```
var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
```

or

```
var keys = getSelectedKeys();
```

but what is the difference between both ways of selections?

Comment: getSelectedKeys(); ? Is this a custom method?

Comment: Anyway, not sure what getSelectedKeys() is, but you should always use `grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();` to retrieve an Array with the selected records.